# Reorder strings using similarity score algorithm

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, similarity, edit-distance

Re-orders a set of strings `{ buzz, fuzz, jazz, fizz..}` so that sum of similarity scores between each pair of adjacent strings is the lowest.

```
buzz-> fuzz (1)
fuzz-> jazz (2)
jazz-> fizz (2)
```

sum of the scores is 5. If reordered based on lowest(4) final output is

```
{ buzz, fuzz, fizz, jazz..}

buzz-> fuzz (1)
fuzz-> fizz (1)
fizz-> jazz (2)
```

My approach is to find Edit distance for every pair of strings and construct a weighted graph where edge represents the edit distance value. Use DFS to find the lowest path. 
Is this the efficient solution? can it be done any better?

Comment: The way you model the problem gives you basically the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem. So this will have exponential runtime (ergo: this solution is not efficient). However, I cannot think of a more efficient way to solve this.

Comment: I believe that you are looking for the shortest Hamiltonian path in a complete graph. Visit each word or vertex once -> Hamiltonian Path. Each word is connected to every other word (with variable weights) -> Complete Graph. Good news. This problem is well known.  :)   Bad news. It is NP-Complete.  :(   
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267377360_Polynomial_Algorithms_for_Shortest_Hamiltonian_Path_and_Circuit

Comment: @SaiBot given a similar problem like this in coding interview to finish in 1 hour. I wasn't sure if what I had is the optimal solution. Wanted to hear the thoughts of the others if I am missing anything.

Comment: You say you were given a "similar" problem in a coding interview, but probably that problem is not similar at all, because it has a good solution that you could code in an hour.  This one does not

Comment: @MattTimmermans I didn't want to mention that this was given as is in the coding interview. Now I just did.

Comment: How do you measure "similarity". See for example [Phonetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Phonetic_algorithms)